# Smartsheet 2.0 api return all sheets in your account

Tags: java, smartsheet-api

Just started making a program to upload data into a smartsheet. Problem is i am getting the error "Invalid Accept header. Media type not supported. " its happening here
`connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(GET_SHEETS_URL).openConnection(); 
connection.addRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);`

here is what i have taken from smartsheet github

```
public class JavaSDKSample {

    private static final String BASE_URL = "https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0";
    private static final String GET_SHEETS_URL = BASE_URL + "/sheets";

    private static final String SHEET_ID = "{sheetId}";
    private static final String SHARE_SHEET_URL = BASE_URL + "/sheet/" + SHEET_ID + "/shares";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();

        //We are using Jackson JSON parser to deserialize the JSON. See http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome
        //Feel free to use which ever library you prefer.
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false); 

        try {
            System.out.println("STARTING HelloSmartsheet...");
            //Create a BufferedReader to read user input.
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

            System.out.print("Enter Smartsheet API access token:");
            String accessToken = in.readLine();
            System.out.println("Fetching list of your sheets...");
            //Create a connection and fetch the list of sheets
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(GET_SHEETS_URL).openConnection();
            connection.addRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            //Read the response line by line.
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(line);
            }
            reader.close();
            //Use Jackson to convert the JSON string to a List of Sheets
            List<Sheet> sheets 
                                = mapper.readValue(response.toString(), new TypeReference<List<Sheet>>() {});
            if (sheets.size() == 0) {
                System.out.println("You don't have any sheets.  Goodbye!");
                return;
            }
            System.out.println("Total sheets: " + sheets.size());
            int i = 1;
            for (Sheet sheet : sheets) {
                System.out.println( i++ + ": " + sheet.name);
            }
            System.out.print("Enter the number of the sheet you want to share: ");

            //Prompt the user to provide the sheet number, the email address, and the access level
            Integer sheetNumber = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine().trim()); //NOTE: for simplicity, error handling and input validation is neglected.
            Sheet chosenSheet = sheets.get(sheetNumber - 1);

            System.out.print("Enter an email address to share " + chosenSheet.getName() + " to: ");
            String email = in.readLine();

            System.out.print("Choose an access level (VIEWER, EDITOR, EDITOR_SHARE, ADMIN) for " + email + ": " );
            String accessLevel = in.readLine();

            //Create a share object
            Share share = new Share();
            share.setEmail(email);
            share.setAccessLevel(accessLevel);

            System.out.println("Sharing " + chosenSheet.name + " to " + email + " as " + accessLevel + ".");


            //Create a connection. Note the SHARE_SHEET_URL uses /sheet as opposed to /sheets (with an 's')
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(SHARE_SHEET_URL.replace(SHEET_ID, "" + chosenSheet.getId())).openConnection();
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.addRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
            connection.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

            OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
            //Serialize the Share object
            writer.write(mapper.writeValueAsString(share));
            writer.close();

            //Read the response and parse the JSON
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            response = new StringBuilder();
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(line);
            }

            Result result = mapper.readValue(response.toString(), Result.class);
            System.out.println("Sheet shared successfully, share ID " + result.result.id);
            System.out.println("Press any key to quit.");
            in.read();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(((HttpURLConnection) connection).getErrorStream()));
            String line;
            try {
                response = new StringBuilder();
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    response.append(line);
                }
                reader.close();
                Result result = mapper.readValue(response.toString(), Result.class);
                System.out.println(result.message);
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Something broke: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static class Sheet {
        Long id;
        String name;

        public Long getId() {
            return id;
        }
        public void setId(Long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
    }

    public static class Share {
        String email;
        String accessLevel;
        Long id;

        public String getEmail() {
            return email;
        }
        public void setEmail(String email) {
            this.email = email;
        }
        public String getAccessLevel() {
            return accessLevel;
        }
        public void setAccessLevel(String accessLevel) {
            this.accessLevel = accessLevel;
        }
        public Long getId() {
            return id;
        }
        public void setId(Long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
    }

    public static class Result {
        String message;
        Share result;

        public String getMessage() {
            return message;
        }

        public void setMessage(String message) {
            this.message = message;
        }

        public Share getResult() {
            return result;
        }

        public void setResult(Share result) {
            this.result = result;
        }
    }        
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! Please make sure to post a easily to read code sample which shows the problem in a compact way and don't post the whole code. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

The error message `Invalid Accept header` is your clue. You need to set the appropriate `Accept` header, in this case `application/json`.

Add the following line just below the line where you set your `connection` variable.

```
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
```

Also, you may be interested in using the existing SDKs that are available for Smartsheet, [listed here](http://www.smartsheet.com/developers/sdks).